# How to add JavaScript to a Twitter Bootstrap Textbox

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I want to be able to add a Javascript call while I am using Twitter-Bootstrap textbox.

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Enter Path</legend>

    @inputText(
    claimLoadingForm("claimLoadingPath"),
    '_label -> "Path",
    '_help -> "Enter a valid path (e.g: /some/path/location/)",
    '_error -> myModuleForm.globalError
    )
</fieldset>
```

Javascript that I have already written offline and tested is as follows.

```
<form id="myform" action="">
<input name="mytext" type="text" onkeyup="validate(this)" onblur="validate(this)">
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
function validate(f) {
        !(/^[A-z/:0-9]*$/i).test(f.value)?f.value = f.value.replace(/[^A-z/:0-9]/ig,''):null;
} 
</script>
```

Question, How do I call onkeyup="validate(this)" onblur="validate(this) from the @indputText

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As you do above, but something indicate that you are using some kind of framework to build your pages / markup with - what is that?

Comment: That framework is Play Framework